# Extract non delimited columns from the delimited column file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

Having file with no delimiters between columns:

```
cat file_no_del 
 aba14092999140932436
 aba1111478991111484975
 aba1111973668111975690
```

How to extract those lines from the original file (with delimiters between columns)? And save it in a new file with delimited columns?

```
cat original_file
 aba1   40929991    40932436
 aba1   100496122   100501188
 aba1   101708714   101709305
 aba1   111478991   111484975
 aba1   111973668   111975690

cat wanted_output
 aba1   40929991    40932436
 aba1   111478991   111484975
 aba1   111973668   111975690
```

I was thinking that it might be possible to do it like this:

```
for i in $(sort orginal_file); do awk '{print $1$2$3}' $i | grep -w - file_no_del
```

But I am having problems with awk & don't know how after greping I should come back in the loop to delimited form.
Hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: How do you know where each column starts?  That is, why does the first row have 8 digit numbers and the others have 9?

Comment: Digit number is variable.

Comment: Are the last two columns always the same length, though? So you could just take the first four characters for the first column and then just split whatever's left in half?

Comment: Digit number in columns ($1,$2,$3)is also variable.

Comment: How would you distinct, from your file without delimiters "aba1 123 456" from "aba1 1234 56" ? If "aba1 12 3456" is in original_file, how do I know if I have to remove it or not ?

Comment: Then I think you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `file_no_del` is small enough, just do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$0]++ } NR!=FNR && a[$1 $2 $3]' file_no_del original_file
```

Comment: +1 But better written as: `awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]++; next } $1 $2 $3 in a' file_no_del original_file` HTH.